# Как скачать файл с одного сервера на другой (напрямую).

Tags: файлы, сервер, debian

сервер1 --------- сервер2

Что мне надо написать в консоли **сервер2**, что бы скачать этот файл с **сервера1**.

Вопрос глуповат, но уже не знаю, как это проделать побыстрее. На обоих машинах Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для простого переноса файла с одного сервера на другой можно пользоваться [scp](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP).

Например, вы хотите перенести файл с сервера A на сервер B. Тогда заходите в консоли на сервер A и выполняем команду

```
$ scp откуда user@host:/directory/куда
```

либо заходим на сервер B и выполняем команду

```
$ scp user@host:/directory/откуда куда
```

чтобы копировать рекурсивно, добавьте опцию `-r`

```
$ scp -r ...
```

Если в поставке еще нет scp, устанавливаем пакет openssh

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

При желании можно настроить openssh так, что пароль не будет требоваться для входа, только ключ.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, каким образом осуществляется связь между серверами. Файл можно скачать по http, ftp, pscp, smb... Смотря что у вас есть в наличии.