# Как передать файл через консоль по SSH с windows10 на Ubuntu (которая на VirtualBox-е)?

Tags: ssh, администрирование, virtualbox

Клиент OpenSSH вместо putty на windows10

в cmd: ssh userName@192.168.x.x

Похожим образом, могу зайти и через putty.

Вот **у меня есть подключение, теперь как передать файл?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SFTP, если открыт порт)

Comment: никак. этим занимается программа scp, идущая в комплекте с программой ssh. см., например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/339502/178576

Comment: Вообще-то, scp. Но если задание учебное, и выполнять его нужно ни жить ни быть в заданном виде, то `type filename.ext |ssh user@remote.host "cat >filename.ext"`. Обратите внимание на то, портит ли команда `type` вашей системы возвраты кареток в своём выводе.

Comment: Задание - это из любопытства. И для удобства перемещения файлов между двумя ОС. Для себя.

Comment: Получилось копировать именно по ssh через консоль. Для этого нужно использовать утилиту PSCP.  https://doc.s-terra.ru/rh_output/4.2/Gate/output/mergedProjects/Appendix/Использование_pscp.exe.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо использовать утилиту [scp](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP) ([пример](https://losst.ru/kopirovanie-fajlov-scp)), под виндой можно попробовать аналог:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:ru

Comment: ура, winscp - это то что надо